# difficulty with MPI_Gather function

Tags: mpi

I have a value on local array (named lvotes) for each of the processors (assume 3 processors), and first element of each is storing a value, i.e.:

```
P0 : 4
P1 : 6
p2 : 7
```

Now, using MPI_Gather, I want gather them all in  P0, so It will look like :

```
P0 : 4, 6, 7
```

I used gather this way:

```
MPI_Gather(lvotes, P, MPI_INT, lvotes, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But I get problems. It's my first time coding in MPI. I could use any suggestion. 
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common issue with people using the gather/scatter collectives for the first time; in both the send and receive counts you specify the count of items to send to or receive from *each* process.   So although it's true that you'll be, in total, getting (say) `P` items, if `P` is the number of processors, that's not what you specify to the gather operation; you specify you are sending a count of 1, and receiving a count of 1 (from each process).  Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    int rank;
    int size;

    int lvotes;
    int *gvotes;

    MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
    MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );

    if (rank == 0)
        gvotes = malloc(size * sizeof(int) );

    /* everyone sets their first lvotes element */
    lvotes = rank+4;

    /* Gather to process 0 */
    MPI_Gather(&lvotes, 1, MPI_INT, /* send 1 int from lvotes.. */
                gvotes, 1, MPI_INT, /* gather 1 int each process into lvotes */
               0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); /* ... to root process 0 */


    printf("P%d: %d\n", rank, lvotes);
    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("P%d: Gathered ", rank);
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            printf("%d ", gvotes[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    if (rank == 0)
        free(gvotes);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Running gives

```
$ mpirun -np 3 ./gather
P1: 5
P2: 6
P0: 4
P0: Gathered 4 5 6
```

Comment: Sweet baby jesus, thank you! I've been fighting with this all day!